# Problem in resampling pandas dataframe with binary value

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe is below:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-08-25 21:00:00','2014-08-25 21:24:00',
                                            '2014-08-25 21:57:00','2014-08-25 22:19:00']))
locations = ['A']
event = [1, 0, 0, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': locations,'Event': event}, index=times)

locations = ['B']
event = [1, 0, 1, 0]

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Location': locations,'Event': event}, index=times))
```

I want to resample this is forward and backward fill the value of 'event'.

My expected output:

```
2014-08-25 21:00:00  A  1
2014-08-25 21:30:00  A  0
2014-08-25 22:00:00  A  0
2014-08-25 22:30:00  A  1
2014-08-25 21:00:00  B  1
2014-08-25 21:30:00  B  0
2014-08-25 22:00:00  B  1
2014-08-25 22:30:00  B  0
```

My approach:

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='30T'), 'Location'])
df_temp = grouper.ffill().unstack()
```

But, this is not giving desired output why?

Comment: Im not quite sure this is a `filling` What should happen if you have multiple values for the same location within a 30 minute time period?

Comment: @ALollz good question. In my case the data is sparse so the said situation wont arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the closure and `label` of the Grouper properly. We'll take the `.first` value, though you can change to `.max` or `.min` if you want to give priority to 1s or 0s respectively in the case of multiple values within the same window.

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='30T', closed='right', label='right'), 'Location'])
   .first()
   .reset_index(level='Location')
   .sort_values('Location')  #  Only so output is sorted like yours
)
```

---

```
                    Location  Event
2014-08-25 21:00:00        A      1
2014-08-25 21:30:00        A      0
2014-08-25 22:00:00        A      0
2014-08-25 22:30:00        A      1
2014-08-25 21:00:00        B      1
2014-08-25 21:30:00        B      0
2014-08-25 22:00:00        B      1
2014-08-25 22:30:00        B      0
```